# Syntax folding of Ifdef/elsif/else/endif Verilog preprocessing keywords

Tags: vim

Verilog supports the following structure of preprocessing keywords:

```
`ifdef A
  `ifdef B
  `else
  `endif
`elsif C
`endif
```

I'm looking for a syntax definition that allows nested folding of the individual elements of this structure, but allowing transparent syntax highlight within it (`contains=ALL`). Below are examples of the desired folding.

I've tried examples of equivalent `#ifdef,#elsif,#endif` examples found in previous questions on StackOverflow, but was not successful in their implementation/porting.

Fold nested keywords:

```
`ifdef A
--  X lines: `ifdef B---------
--  X lines: `else------------
`elsif C
`endif
```

Fold top level `` `ifdef ``:

```
--  X lines: `ifdef A---------
`elsif C
`endif
```

Fold top level `` `elsif ``:

```
`ifdef A
  `ifdef B
  `else
  `endif
--  X lines: `elsif C---------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Syntax folding of Vim scripts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Syntax_folding_of_Vim_scripts); it provides such syntax definitions for Vimscript. If you're somewhat familiar with Vim's syntax highlighting, you should be able to adapt that to the Verilog syntax.

Comment: I was following that guide, but did not copy&paste it directly. It appears the `contains=` and `contained=` is really important... thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. As others may be interested in your extension, why don't you publish that somewhere, either as a syntax plugin on http://www.vim.org/, or more quickly as a Gist, with a link added here as a comment?!

Comment: Everything is or will be included in a fork I made of the `verilog_systemverilog` plugin that can be found [here](http://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim). Feel free to take a look and suggest improvements! Eventually it might make sense to include this as an upgrade for Verilog syntax in vim-runtime, but I don't think it is in a good enough state at the moment.